# Mark a class as abstract without defining any abstract methods

Tags: python

I'm looking for something like this:

```
from abc import ABC

@abstractclass
class A(ABC):
    pass

A()  # FAILS

class B(A):
    pass

B()  # SUCCEEDS
```

I'm aware of the option of decorating the c'tor or some dummy method in `A` with `abstractmethod`, but this requires me to override it in `B`. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why doing this?  The whole point of an abc is used to require all abstract methods be defined in derived classes.  If you don't have any abstract methods, then trivially "all" of them are defined, and there is no point to using an abc in the first place.

Comment: There are semantic reasons to define a class as abstract even though the class may be fully implemented syntactically.

Comment: @wim a class inheriting from an abstract mixin may implement all its methods but still leave some attributes undefined.

Comment: @wim: You might want to use an abstract base class to hold all the behavior and attributes that are common to all of its concrete subclasses; and yet only allow users to instantiate the subclasses rather than the base class itself. E.g., You might want to allow creation of a Cat or a Dog but not instances of their base class, Animal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize `__new__`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls is A:
            raise TypeError("Can't instantiate abstract class {}".format(A.__name__))
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

class B(A):
    pass

A()  # TypeError
B()  # Ok
```

You can also make it decorator-style, for example like this (works as long as the decorated class didn't customize `__new__`):

```
def abstractclass(decorated_cls):
    def clsnew(cls):
        if cls is decorated_cls:
            raise TypeError("Can't instantiate abstract class {}".format(decorated_cls.__name__))
        return super(decorated_cls, cls).__new__(cls)
    decorated_cls.__new__ = clsnew
    return decorated_cls

@abstractclass
class A(ABC):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

A()  # TypeError
B()  # Ok
```

Comment: Searched a lot for such idea. Nice one. +1